# Update Object with an array using React States

Tags: reactjs

I have a state `quiz` and another one `questionList` and the following quiz structure is like this:

```
const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState({
        title: 'test',
        description: 'test',
        user_id: 'test',
        thumbnail: 'test',
        timer: 'test',
        question: []
    })
```

And somehow the structure of `questionList` is:

```
[{
   id: Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000),
   question: "data",
   answer1: "data",
   answer2: "data",
   answer3: "data",
   answer4: "data"
},
{
   id: Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000),
   question: "data",
   answer1: "data",
   answer2: "data",
   answer3: "data",
   answer4: "data"
}
]
```

So with a function, I'm filling the `questionList` but what I want to do is also beside that update (or replace) the `question: []` with the new array from the `questionList` in the `quiz` state.

Here is how I add a question in the List:

```
const addQuestion = (question) => {
   setQuestionList([...questionList, question]);   
   // here the logic to update the property question on Quiz state with the new added object into questionList
};
```

So when a question is added to the list, that list array I want to update to questions: [], as an update, and not add another field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in your function,
replace your old function,

```
const addQuestion = (question) => {
   setQuestionList([...questionList, question]); 
};
```

to this, this will work

```
const addQuestion = (question) => {
   setQuestionList([...questionList, question]);   
   setQuiz({...quiz, question: [...questionList, question]})
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useEffect` hook with questionList state. And when questionList updated, this hook triggered and updates quiz state.

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
  setQuiz({...quiz, question: questionList})
}, [questionList]);
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically what i understand from your question .when new question added it should add in your questionList array.
so in react we cannot directly mutate states.
[1]: https://medium.com/@kkranthi438/dont-mutate-state-in-react-6b25d5e06f42
So in order to solve this we can

1. Create a new dummy object.

   ```
   const addQuestion = (question) => {
   let dummyObj={};//set all your properties here inside your question array also
   ```
2. copy existing array into dummy array

   ```
   let dummyArr=[...existing array];
   ```
3. push object or other values in this array

   ```
   dummmyArr.push(dummyObj);//push only work here not for pushing into setState
   ```
4. now put this mutated array into your setState .

   ```
   setQuestionList(dummyArr)
   };
   ```

now this method is also suitable if you want to set nested data like youyr question array.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution you can use useEffect for that purpose
1- use Dependency array of useEffect .Every time state of question list change .this will automatically trigger the useEffect.

Comment: yes thats a way too

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're almost there, just need to update your `questionList` first and then `quiz`.

Notice the callback style of setting state.

```
const addQuestion = (question) => {
   setQuestionList(prevQuestionList => [...prevQuestionList, question]);   
};
```

and later add reaction to `questionList` changing

```
useEffect(() => {
   setQuiz(prevQuiz => ({...prevQuiz, question: questionList}))
}, [questionList])
```